# Why is the Create a new service application button disabled and the link not active in Central Admin?

Tags: service-application

When I go to manage service applications in Central Administration and try to create a new service application like: New > Create a new service application, the link isn't active.
My issue is I would like to create a  Search Service Application after installing Search Server Express 2010.

Do I need to run the Farm Configuration Wizard and install the below if I can create a Search Service Application?

> **Business Data Connectivity Service**
>
> Enabling this service provides the
> SharePoint farm with the ability to
> upload BDC models that describe the
> interfaces of your enterprises' line
> of business systems and thereby access
> the data within these systems.
>
> **State Service**
>
> Provides temporary storage of
> user session data for SharePoint
> Server components.
>
> **Usage and Health data collection**
>
> This service collects
> farm wide usage and health data and
> provides the ability to view various
> usage and health reports.

**Update 1:**

I'm running Windows 2008 R2. I migrated WSS v3 to SharePoint Foundation 2010 and then installed Search Express 2010 on top of it.

I am logged in with an account that has full farm administration access.

**Update 2:**

I migrated WSS v3 to Sharepoint Foundation 2010 and then installed Search Express 2010 on top of it.

**Update 3:**

Yes the farm admin acct is the member of the local admin.
What services are required to start to have the possibility to create a new search service apps? The only new link i can see on the service application page menu is to create BDC service.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/13f9bedb07.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/13f9bedb07.jpg)

Comment: @Patrick: Please make an effort to use this system properly. Most of all this *helps you get good answers*. If your post isn't gaining attention, **edit it with more details** on what you have tried. If you are responding to someone that has left you an answer, please **leave a comment on their answer**. Thank you

Comment: Run Internet Explorer as Administrator and open Central Administration site.

Comment: You can follow steps in this link

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/30962/29811

Answer (score 4):

is the UAC enable? So you have to open the Central Administration from start windows menu instead of opening a browser and type the url of the Central Administration...
...or disable UAC.

Comment: ran into this recently. that's my first bet.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 2008R2 + SharePoint 2013. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Are you running on Windows 7? If that is the case make sure that your Internet Explorer (or other browser) is running with elevated privilegies.

Answer (score 1):

Is your farm administrator account member of the local administrator group on the farm servers? This is required to start services.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in with an account that has full farm administration access?  Are you using Foundation or the full server version?