# SP2013: Create a new Service Application button is greyed out in CA

Tags: central-administration

I am in the central admin of SP2013 onpremise. I logged in as a farm account. I can create webapplications, sitecollections etc. But now I try to create a new service application, but the button is greyed out. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible solution can be found here:

[Why is the Create a new service application button disabled and the link not active in Central Admin?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/why-is-the-create-a-new-service-application-button-disabled-and-the-link-not-act)

> is the UAC enable? So you have to open the Central Administration from
>   start windows menu instead of opening a browser and type the url of
>   the Central Administration... ...or disable UAC.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Central Administration with Run As Administration option and see.